# Random formula based of 15 seeds

Tags: c, random, adc

I am working at my university degree and I got stuck at a random function.
I am using a microcontroller, which has no configured clock. So, I decided to use the ADC (analog to digital conversion) as seeds for my random function.

So I have 15 two bytes variables with stores some 'random' values ( the conversion is not always the same, and the difference is at the LSB ( the last bit in my case :eg now the value of an adc read is 700, in 5ms it is 701, then back to 700, then 702 etc). So, I was thinking to build a random function with use the last 4 bits lets say from those variables.

My question is: Can you give me an example of a good random formula?

Like `( Variable1 >> 4 ) ^ ( Variable2 << 4 )` and so on ...

I want to be able to obtain a pretty random number on 1 byte ( this is the best case ). It will be used in a RSA algorithm, which I have already implemented ( I have a big look up table with prime numbers, and I need 2 random numbers from that table ).

Comment: I add also an software clock ( more like an 4 bytes variable which increments by 5,  from 5 to 5 ms ). I was thinking that this will help my ADC reads be more random, doing some operations with this variable as well.

Comment: Uh uh... big lookup table with prime numbers to be use for RSA? That will certainly not be secure...

Comment: I can't tell the "big picture", but be sure that it will be safe enough. It's not such a sophisticated thing, its just a feature to my project. It should not be prefect, but i am trying to focus on the way i am building the algorithms.

Comment: Are you aware of this? https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.3777.pdf

Comment: If 700 has a much higher probablility than other numbers you would have to factor that in too somehow or the random numbers are not evenly distributed. Also lookup table doesn't sound very secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a cryptographic hash function like SHA or MD5 is used for this purpose.  As long as your input data contains enough entropy, you will get a random output.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(computing)

However, that may be a little too much work for your use case.  If you only need 8 bits, you could use an 8-bit cyclic redundancy code (CRC).  It will have similar properties -- since any 8 of your input bits can be used to completely determine the output, the output will be random as long as at least 8 of your input bits are random.  See http://www.sunshine2k.de/articles/coding/crc/understanding_crc.html

That will do what you ask for... but beware!  It sounds like you are writing a completely insecure implementation of RSA.  Under no circumstances could you use only 8 bits of randomness to securely generate an RSA key.

Answer (score 1):

If you think that the LS bit of every word is truly random (which is likely), and if they are *uncorrelated*, pack 8 LS bits into 1 byte. There is no use for the remaining 15 x 16 - 8 bits.